# Create database with name and path from variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a database where its name and data path are taken from a variable, e.g:

```
declare @DataPath nvarchar(200) = cast(serverproperty('InstanceDefaultDataPath') as nvarchar(200));

declare @Database nvarchar(50) = 'MyDatabaseName';

use master
go

if exists (select name from sys.databases where name = '@Database')
drop database [@Database]
go

create database [@Database] 
on primary ( 
  name = '@Database',
  filename = concat(@Datapath, '@Database_Data.mdf'),
  size = 200MB,
  maxsize = 20GB,
  filegrowth = 40MB 
)
collate Latin1_General_CI_AI

go
```

I get the error "Incorrect syntax near '('." on code line:

```
  filename = concat(@Datapath, '@Database_Data.mdf'),
```

Why?

Comment: You'll need dynamic SQL for this - you cannot pass parameters to these commands in standard T-SQL

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Comment: Read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) - you basically have to build your SQL statement as a string, and then execute that string as a SQL command

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use

```
name = @Database, 
filename = concat(@Datapath, @Database,'_Data.mdf'),
```

instead?

Comment: `concat()` is maybe only allowed in a  `SET` or `SELECT` clause?